# How to Force ObjectUtil.copy() to copy Transient attribute

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, copy, transient

I'd like to force the method ObjectUtil.copy() to copy the transient attribute...

Do you have a solution to do that?Or do you know another method to copy my Object?

Thank you very much,

Bat

Comment: What is the transient attribute?  A property on the class?  Or are you referring to metadata?

Comment: I personally don't think "I don't understand the question" is a good reason to down vote the question. A transient attribute is an attribute marked with the [Transient] metadata tag so that it does not get sent back to the server. No, I don't have the answer, but I am upvoting it so people don't think there's something wrong with the question.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I think the question is unclear; which is why I asked the follow-up questions.  Metadata is an aspect of a class; and is not something that needs to be copied between instances of the class.  Thanks to MXML, the generic term "attributes" can refer to properties, or instance variables, or styles, or event listeners.  It is unclear what this poster wants to do. I didn't understand the question because it was poorly written. That is why I downvoted.

Comment: A property is marked with metadata and that makes it transient. It's not the metadata that needs to be coied, but the property. Apparently, marking the attribute as transient prevents it from being copied (which makes sense). English isn't everyone's first language, and this question is fine.

Comment: Indeed, for me a transient attribute means I define my attribute like this : [Transient] public var MyVar:String. I understand that the definition of 'transient' means that it'll not send to the server and by the way will not be copied by the function ObjectUtil.copy(). However my question is, do you know an another solution to make a copy of an object that has transient attributes? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that with the getter function, I put a condition in ma getter function to know if I'm in a context in wich one I want to copy the transient variable or no

```
public function get myVar():Object {
if (WantCopyTransient)
  return _myVar;
else
  return null;
}
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

`[Transient]` and `byteArray.writeObject()` are both native player implementations.  There's no way to modify their behaviour / implementation.

You'd need to look into writing your own copy util method.

Comment: I am in a similar situation. How do I manually copy all attributes including transients ?